# turn off point values in radar chart

Tags: charts, chart.js, radar-chart

I'm using Chart-Js and am trying to create a radar chart.  How do you remove the point values in the image below?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to remove the values and not remove the points where the values are? Im confuse

Comment: have you included a labels plugin? it would be a separate `.js` file, if so, remove it -- otherwise, it would be helpful to see the code...

Comment: I'm using the default implementation.  I solved it by adding this:  Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 0;

Answer (score 0):

I'm needing to remove the numbers from the dots in the graph.  I'm using the default implementation of ng2-charts which is an Angular plugin for Chart.js.  I solved the problem by adding this:

Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 0;

This is probably not the best solution, but it got me past this hump.

Thanks